# Is it safe to edit the packages.config file in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, reference, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, packages.config

I removed Microsoft.ApplicationInsights from my Windows Store (8.1) app, but it keeps coming back (with a yellow warning glyph) beneath "References". It doesn't seem to really cause much mayhem, but I'd still like to completely get rid of it out of this project.

When I remove the reference, it goes away, but then comes back later. Is it because of what remains behind in packages.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Callisto" version="1.4.0" targetFramework="win81" />
  <package id="ExifLib" version="1.6.3.0" targetFramework="win81" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" version="0.10.0-build17704" targetFramework="win81" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.RuntimeTelemetry" version="0.10.0-build17704" targetFramework="win81" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsStore" version="0.10.0-build17704" targetFramework="win81" />
  <package id="sqlite-net" version="1.0.8" targetFramework="win81" />
</packages>
```

?

If so, is it safe to strip the three references to Microsoft.ApplicationInsights directly out of packages.config?

---

**EDIT:**

I removed the ApplicationInsights reference, stripped out the three references to ApplicationInsights from package.config, built the project (fine), closed the project, re-opened the project, and the dad-burned ApplicationInsight reference was back again (packages.config remained pristine).

Comment: `packages.config` is generated by Nuget. It contains the Nuget packages the project relies upon. It is safe to remove those references, so long as they are not used in your application.

Comment: I wonder if you have it added to your solution packages and nuget is restoring the reference each time. May be worth investigating.

Comment: How would I investigate that? If I did, it wasn't intentionally.

Comment: Try right clicking your solution and click `Manage Nuget Packages for the Solution`. See if it's in the Installed packages (at the top left).

Comment: Nope - the only things in Installed packages are (as they should be), ExifLib and sqlite-net

I removed Callisto, too, as 8.1 is more full-controlled and obviates my need for Callisto. It (Callisto), BTW, behaves politely - it doesn't intrude upon the approved References after having been asked to leave, as ApplicationInsights does. Was ApplicationInsights underwritten by the NSA, by any chance?

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23228704/remove-application-insight-from-application-on-visual-studio-2013), you may need to remove the **Telemetry SDK for Services** nuget package.

Comment: Thanks for the research; I don't see that still existing anywhere in my project, though. I did already remove Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.RuntimeTelemetry, so...???

Comment: Did you remove it with nuget? Or by deleting it from the packages config? Also, maybe try reinstalling the sdks, then removing them as described in the link?

Comment: I removed them as References, and thereafter from packages.config