# Completely Remove ApplicationInsights from Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, azure-application-insights

I've looked around, and haven't been able to find a good answer, so I'm posting this question in the hopes that it can be a sort of "go to" for others hoping to entirely remove Application Insights.

The first, and move obvious thing I tried was uninstalling the Tool from the Tools and Extensions, but unfortunately this made things worse! Now I'm not able to create MVC projects at all, due to missing DLLs.

I tried searching for templates that might include AI as well, but couldn't find any, so I'm stuck wondering where else it is buried that it can cause these sorts of issues. Has anyone out there successfully, completely removed AI?

Comment: what errors did you have after uninstalling our extension?  just uninstalling the extension from `tools->extensions and updates` should not remove any dll's that anyone else would be depending on.  If you deleted from `settings->add remove programs`, that's a different story and would break stuff.  Let me know what errors you see, and i'll let you know how to fix them.  What was broken that you need to uninstall it in the first place?  let me know, so we can fix that too: jgardner at microsoft.

Comment: Hi @JohnGardner -- thanks a ton for responding. I actually ended up re-installing VS2015 to fix the problem, but I will re-uninstall the AI stuff this afternoon and try to shoot you the details of the error.

Comment: thanks for the info!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *easiest* way is to disable the extension from `tools->extensions and updates` window, and restarting VS.  All of our features should disappear, since VS will no longer load our extension.

*Uninstalling* the extension from `tools->extensions and updates` should **not** break anything, as there are no dependencies on our *extension*.  Internally, we do this all the time for testing ourselves.

**HOWEVER**, uninstalling the entire feature from `Add->Remove Programs` **can** and **will** break things, since that will also uninstall our interfaces assembly, which other features, like ASP.NET presume to exist.

Comment: The second time that I removed AI (via Tools and Extensions), I did not encounter the same set of errors. It appears that removing through this view should be sufficient. I'm tempted to believe that I may have uninstalled through the Remove Program flow last time, which may account for the issues I was seeing. Will update If I encounter it again.

Comment: AI is not listed in 2017 - could you provide instructions on how to remove for Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: in later versions of VS2015 and VS2017, it is called "Developer Analytics Tools".  in VS2017, if you don't want it, it is an optional component in the Visual Studio Installer, so you can skip it completely at first install time.  You should still be able to disable it, etc from `tools->extensions and updates` though?

Comment: @JohnGardner Thanks a lot John. You should update your answer as this seems to pretty important info.

Answer (score 0):

On my PC I tried to uninstall AI, I go to Add or remove program and uninstall the application insight.

Next time when I create the asp.net mvc web-application it doesn't work (it's show me error like HRESULT ....). So if you are trying to remove it, please don't do it, it will break your visual studio.

Best you can do is remove it from Nuget package for your solution or save your sollution as the template (it will save your time next time you want to create a project without application insight).

Comment: if you don't want to Add AI to new projects, you can simply uncheck the Application Insights checkbox in the right side of the `file->new project` window.  once you've unchecked that once, we remember it and never turn it back on, and you'll never get the AI nuget packages installed after that until you turn it back on yourself.