# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, azure-application-insights

I have two web applications under IIS 7 (local Windows 10 Pro). At the root is an MVC .Net Version 4.7.1. Everything seems to work fine here so far. However, set up as a separate application under the default site root is an older .Net Version 4.0 WebForms application.

The version 4 application is built in Visual Studio 2015 and the MVC is built using Visual Studio 2017. I have the version 4 WebForms app running under a different website with the same settings and it runs fine. It only has a problem when running under the root node as a different application. Also I have tried using different App Pools on both application as well as using the same App Pool with no change in the error.

I have also tried uninstalling ApplicationInsights and disabling it and I get the same issue.

> [FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
>     System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
>     System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName) +95
>     System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +64
>     System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +60
>     System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, XmlNode node, Boolean checkAptcaBit, Boolean ignoreCase) +49
>
> [ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
>     System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, XmlNode node, Boolean checkAptcaBit, Boolean ignoreCase) +558
>     System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, Boolean checkAptcaBit) +30
>     System.Web.Configuration.Common.ModulesEntry.SecureGetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement) +57
>     System.Web.Configuration.Common.ModulesEntry..ctor(String name, String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement) +57
>     System.Web.HttpApplication.BuildIntegratedModuleCollection(List`1 moduleList) +182
>     System.Web.HttpApplication.GetModuleCollection(IntPtr appContext) +1086
>     System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +120
>     System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +169
>     System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +372
>     System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +329
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
>     System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +525
>     System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +118
>     System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +708

Answer (score 13):

In my case, sub app wasn't using ApplicationInsights and I added these exclusions to the sub app **web.config** file. It fixed the problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
      <remove name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" />
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
    </modules> 
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Here is the discussing topic where I have found my answer https://github.com/aspnet/Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation/issues/21#issuecomment-508535397

My answer is a late answer but it might help someone else.

Answer (score 4):

I also face the same issue when i am working with an application inside the default website in iis. Please remove all .net files from root(in my case root is Default Web Site) then it will work.

Comment: How to delete .net files from root ? Please elaborate it... -Thanks

Comment: I had created an application inside Default Website so that I deleted all files inside the folder which is assigned to Default Web Site

Comment: Did you finally got both application working, @PrincePrasad? I do not understand well, if you delete all files, you deleted the root application, didn't you?

Comment: Yes.. In my case i deleted the root application.

Comment: Deleting the web.config in the site root fixed it for me.

Answer (score 4):

You can use NugetPackage Manager and browse for `Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation` and install it.

Answer (score 0):

Stanley.

If i understand you correctly, i would recommend the following:

Navigate to the WebForms instance that works perfectly. In that directory do a search for files that contain the word 'Telemetry'. You should find a couple of .dll's.

Do the same search in the WebForms directory that does NOT work.
you should find noting or less files.

I would copy the 'Telemetry' files from the working instance to the broken instance(matching the directories) and see what happens. !?

As per the error the code its trying to load missing files. --could not load file or assembly.(FileNotFoundException)

Comment: The working site actually points to the same location as the application that is under the root of the default website in IIS. I just created another site in IIS to see if it worked on its own. So both the working one and the one that is not working is using the exact same files.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37418603/completely-remove-applicationinsights-from-visual-studio-2015) that shows how to disable ApplicationInsights. Doing that did not actually fix the issue, but then I went in and removed all signs of it in Nuget packages and the config file at the root of my project. Once I got that done the error no longer occurs.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to cleanup my applicationhost.config file for the sites in my .vs directory which I think was alluded to in other answers.

I had a different root "/" path configured which seemed like it might have been the source of the conflict.