# Why is my MVC/Angular App throwing "Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation not found" when trying to launch in prod?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, angular7, iis-7.5

I am new to angular, but have been following a tutorial on Angular MVC Web API. I have already used the build command that generates the `dist` folder and files and created an application in IIS that points to that `dist` folder. Here's what I have tried:

- Deleting and copying over the bin and packages.config file.
- Updated the `Microsoft.ASPNet.Telemetry` package, compiled and ensured that the application was running before deleting the project from the prod server and copying it back to the server and adding the rewrite command in my web.config.
- Ensured that Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation was in the bin folder.

The MVC portion that I am using for the API works as I am able to navigate to it from the server. I have also ensured that `Network Service` and `IIS_User` has full control. However, when I try to launch the application pointing to the dist folder I keep getting the following error:

**Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you could try to install Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation by using negate package manager or run this command to install it: pm>Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation -Version 1.0.7. for more detail refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50949255/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-aspnet-telemetrycorrelation-or-one-o)

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:
https://github.com/aspnet/Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation/issues/21#issuecomment-508535397

Use it for your Angular app.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
      <remove name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" />
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
    </modules> 
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```